# About voice filtering

Tags: fft, filters, voice

I have a waveform containing

1. voice
2. some children screaming
3. some times when there is no noise at all
4. some times there are cars driving by when talking

I want to detect the start and ending times of the loudest voice or the areas in which the same speaker is talking to cut them out.

What I did was a FFT on the waveform to realize that voice means there is(in a small time unit of a few ms) always a high amplitude at the base frequency to be followed by equidistant frequencies, being apart in the integral multiple of the base frequency.

But this also applied to some noises.

The goal is to detect voice and cut the parts containing voice out(ie. keep them) with all background sounds. It is not about only having voice but finding out where voice is and cutting it out with all cars children or whatever was surrounding the microphone while recording. The problem is that I get many false positives when music(no voice) is being played or some squealing sound can be heard.

What is a better approach to filter out the times voice is at in a wav file with these given features?

Comment: It is a little unclear what the actual goal is here, but doing something like identifying a particular human voice is quite a complex task.  You probably don't want to implement this from scratch.  You may want to ask about voice processing tool kits that provide ready made functions to perform the tasks you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think filtering is the way to go. The spectra of the different signals (the desired voice, the screamy children and the cars) are probably overlapping, so there is no real way to get rid of all that noise without spoiling your signal.

Actually, the approach would depend in how loud the noise is in comparison to the signal. If the speaker is near the microphone, and therefore the relative noise level is ''low'', this sounds like a [VAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) kind of problem.

If noise level is quite low, an energy-based VAD may work: after [windowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) the input signal (let's say to 20ms windows), each window's energy can be computed. Then, a threshold can be applied in order to decide if that window is noise or voice. You would simply discard the windows that aren't load enough to meet the threshold. This is unarguably the simplest approach.

A simple improvement to this kind of VAD, assuming you only have one speaker, is to reduce the bandwidth in which you apply the stated algorithm. This way, if the kids voice spectrum begins at about e.g. 500Hz, and the cars induce some low frequencies up to e.g. 80Hz, you could use a band pass (e.g. 100Hz - 300Hz, assuming the speaker fundamental frequency is about 200Hz) filtered signal to decide wether each window is or isn't noise, and select those who aren't in the original signal. I know this is not ideal, as too many coincidences are needed to have a reliable system.

Unfortunately, this won't work when noise gets louder. Furthermore, some phonems may be discarded due to their low energy, such as /s/ or /z/. This just makes speech sound weird. There are some more advanced VAD techniques such as [Sohn's *A Statistical Model-Based Voice Activity Detection*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.34.550&rep=rep1&type=pdf). You can find some Matlab implementations in the net. I have used this in addition to spectral substraction noise reduction (which doesn't seem to be needed in your case) in a noisy environment (babble + WGN) and results were susprisingly good.

---

Matlab code for using Voicebox's Sohn VAD.

```
in_file='yourfile.wav';
[s,fs,wmode,fidx]=readwav(in_file,'p',-1,3500); %3500 is the number of samples to discard at the beginning of your file. 
[y1,zo]=vadsohn(s,fs); %y1 is 1 when there is voice, 0 when there isn't
y=s(1:length(y1)).*y1; %apply mask
y(1)=0;

for i=2:length(y)
    if y(i-1)<y(i)
        StartTime=(i-2)/fs
    elseif y(i-1)>y(i)
        EndTime=(i-2)/fs
    end
end
```

Comment: The goal is to detect voice and cut the parts containing voice out(ie. keep them) with all background sounds. It is not about only having voice but finding out where voice is and cutting it out with all cars children or whatever was surrounding the microphone while recording. The problem is that I get many false positives when music(no voice) is being played or some squealing sound can be heard.

Comment: Do you know an implementation for c# or an automatic converter?

Comment: I think you could do some testing in Matlab with Sohn's algorithm ( http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/vadsohn.html ) and, if you find a way to get it working, try something like this http://www.mathworks.es/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12987-integrating-matlab-with-c . Bear in mind that the task is actually quite difficult if SNR is low and there is wide band noise (i.e. music) in your signal. That's why I'm sure statistical modelling is worth a shot here.

Comment: Please give me an example command line for http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/vadsohn.html under matlab. Or in other words, what to use for si, fsz, m and pp when using a wav file

Comment: @Zurechtweiser I updated the answer for you, hope it helps. Then you can play around with the other arguments for vadsohn to get better results. Don't forget to add the whole voicebox package to Matlab's active path (e.g. using `addpath('yourpath')`.

Comment: I got "Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree." after "y=s(1:length(s)).*y1; %apply mask" - ideas?

Comment: @Zurechtweiser sorry for the mistake, you can use `y=s(1:length(y1)).*y1; %apply mask` instead.

Comment: Alright, so when I type in y after that I get a list. What does that list mean? As I said, what I need is a StartTime1=X,EndTime1=Y,StartTime2=X,EndTime2=Y,... type of output where EndTime1 < StartTime2 etc.

Comment: @Zurechtweiser that list is the output signal. you can use `sound(y,fs)` to hear it. In order to find the transitions, you can use something as the code I have included in my answer.